# Solving logarithm problem, Found the value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is my first question in this place, I don't know how to solve my problem.

I have this equation, I need to find the central value based on this equation:

$k = 0.2$

$$k = 2^{(\frac{1}{24} + \frac{1}{24\cdot2^x})}-2^{(\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{24\cdot2^x})}$$

I need to figure out the ***x*** value, the known value is ***k***.
$$x=?$$

if I define ***y*** like: $y = \frac{1}{24\cdot2^{x}}= 2^{-x}/24$,  and ***l*** like:  $l = k/2^{\frac{1}{24}}$

$$k = 2^{\frac{1}{24}}\cdot2^y-2^{\frac{1}{24}}\cdot2^{-y}$$

$$l = 2^y-2^{-y}$$

$$\log_{2}(l)=\text{ ?}$$

$$y=\text{ ?}$$

Please help me.

Comment: $l=2^y-2^{-y}=2^y-\dfrac{1}{2^y}=\dfrac{2^y\cdot2^y-1}{2^y}=\dfrac{2^{2y}-1}{2^y}$

Comment: $\log_{2}(l)=\log_{2}\left(\dfrac{2^{2y}-1}{2^y}\right)=\log_{2}(2^{2y}-1)-\log_{2}(2^y)\approx\log_{2}(2^{2y})-\log_{2}(2^y)=2^{2y}-2^y$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both side of $l=2^{y}-2^{-y}$ by $2^{y}$ you will get
$$
A^{2}-Al-1=0,
$$
where $A=2^{y}$. Solving this equation with respect to $A$ gives the desired values for $A$.

Comment: is there mistake? l=2^(y)−2^(−y)  ==>> l*2^(y) = 2^(2y)-2^(0) ==>>  l*2^(y) = 2^(2y)-1 ==>> 2^(2y)-l*2^(y)-1=0, if A = 2^(y) then ==>>  A^(2)-l*A-1=0

Comment: Yes. sorry, you are right and so the equation always has real roots (for $l^{2}+4\geq  0$).

Answer (score 1):

$$k=2^{\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{24\cdot2^x}}-2^{\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{24\cdot2^x}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$k=2^{\frac{2^{-x}+1}{24}}-2^{\frac{1-2^{-x}}{24}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$k=2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}\sinh\left(\frac{2^{-3-x}\ln(2)}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}=\sinh\left(\frac{2^{-3-x}\ln(2)}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}\right)=\frac{2^{-3-x}\ln(2)}{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$3\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}\right)=2^{-3-x}\ln(2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}\right)}{\ln(2)}=2^{-3-x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}\right)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}=-3-x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}\right)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}+3=-x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=-\left[\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{24}}}\right)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}+3\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{3\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\sqrt[24]{2}}\right)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)}-3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=-\frac{\ln\left(\frac{24\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{k}{2\sqrt[24]{2}}\right)}{\ln(2)}\right)}{\ln(2)}$$

---

EDIT:

In general:

$$2^{\frac{a+1}{x}}-2^{\frac{1-a}{x}}=2^{\frac{1-a}{x}}\left(4^{\frac{a}{x}}-1\right)$$

Comment: Can you explain me, the conversion of SinH = (e^(x) - e^(-x))/2 or using property in the Step 2 to Step 3?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set $a=1/24$ and $t=2^{-x}$, so the equation becomes
$$
k=2^{a+at}-2^{a-at}
$$
We now see a further simplification: set $b=2^a$, so the equation becomes
$$
k=b^{1+t}-b^{1-t}
$$
or else
$$
k=bb^t-\frac{b}{b^t}
$$
that can be rewritten as
$$
bb^{2t}-kb^t-b=0
$$
This is a quadratic in $b^t$ and we can immediately discard the negative root, so
$$
b^t=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4b^2}}{2b}
$$
Therefore
$$
t=\frac{\log(k+\sqrt{k^2+4b^2})-\log b-\log 2}{\log b}
$$
Recalling that $t=2^{-x}$ we get
$$
-x\log 2=\log\frac{\log(k+\sqrt{k^2+4b^2})-\log b-\log 2}{\log b}
$$
The logarithm can be with respect to any basis, the formula is simpler if we use base $2$, so $\log_2b=\log_22^a=a$ and $\log_22=1$, so
$$
-x=\log_2\frac{\log_2(k+\sqrt{k^2+4b^2})-a-1}{a}
$$
Since $b=2^a$ we have $b^2=2^{2a}$ and $4b^2=2^{2+2a}$ and we have
$$
x=\log_2\frac{a}{\log_2(k+\sqrt{k^2+2^{2+2a}})-a-1}
$$